# How to give different input fields different values on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I use a function to clear the input values of form fields in a container:

```
function clear_form_elements(ele) {

$(ele).find(':input').each(function() {
    switch(this.type) {
        case 'password':
        case 'select-multiple':
        case 'select-one':
        case 'text':
        case 'textarea':
            $(this).val('');
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'radio':
            this.checked = false;
    }
});}
```

this completely clears a set of input fields inside a div, fieldset or similar (defined as ele). Now I tried to replace the

```
$(this).val('');
```

with

```
if(this.id = "town") {this.val('town');}
if(this.id = "country") {this.val('country');}
```

to replace input elements with different IDs but the value returned for each input field is always "country" even though the ID of the element is different.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should your this.val have $(this).val() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
if(this.id = "town") {this.val('town');}
if(this.id = "country") {this.val('country');}
```

to

```
if(this.id == "town") {this.val('town');}
if(this.id == "country") {this.val('country');}
```

(double equals)

Your statement will always return true after setting values. you are trying to compare, not to set a value.